# Trying to use getfilenamewithextension in LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, list, file

Please bear with me I'm not to hot on LINQ and even less on C# but I have the following statement that's causing me a headache:

```
myList = myClass.Where(f => f.OrigiFilename == origiFilename).ToList();
```

It works okay currently but needs changing.

I understand the where clause returns a result set of filenames and we are going to compare them to the variable

```
origiFilename
```

So we essence we are comparing like so: file1.txt == file1, file2.doc == file1, file3.pdf == file1

However, what must happen is we want to ignore the file extension that is returned from

```
f.OrigiFilename
```

I'd ideally want to use Get File Name Without Extension but I can't seem to do this in LINQ or be able to switch to C# to do this and then back.

Any LINQ experts out there ever have to do this?

I do have a workaround which is add the lot into the list and then move though the list again removing each using C# but this isn't ideal, I want it all done in one statement...

Comment: _myList = myClass.Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.OrigiFilename) == origiFilename).ToList();_

Comment: Are you trying to run this **in a database query**? (You've tagged your question as Sql Server, so could be LinqToSql or EF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to keep the query on the database side, there isn't an easy way to jump back to C#, however, you can do the following, which should translate into decent SQL query, albeit there are some differences and will fail if there are multiple extensions on the filename:

```
myList = myClass.Where(f => f.OrigiFilename.StartsWith(origiFilename+".")).ToList();
```

Comment: Looks to be the best solution, thanks (to let others know get file name without extension would be ideal but produces an error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.")

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
myClass
    .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.OrigiFilename) == origiFilename)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Path` class contains a `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` method that you can use:

```
myList = myClass
    .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.OrigiFilename) == origiFilename)
    .ToList();
```